# XSL: Using tokenize to generate list of .dot digraph connections?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm an XSL newbie by most means. Just saying that in advance. :)

I'm trying to transform XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl"?>
<root>
    <node>
        <name>A</name>
        <out>D, B, C, </out>
    </node>

    <node>
        <name>B</name>
        <out>A, E, C, </out>
    </node>

</root>
```

into a .dot file that looks like this:

```
Digraph G
{
    A -> D 
    A -> B 
    A -> C 
    B -> A
    B -> E
    B -> C
}
```

using XSL. What I have so far of the XSL,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
Digraph G
{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/node/out"/>
}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/node/out">
 <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="." /> 
 </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
 <xsl:param name="csv" />
  <xsl:variable name="iter" select="normalize-space( 
    substring-before( concat( $csv, ','), ','))" /> 
 <xsl:if test="$iter">
 <!-- X is a placeholder -->
  X -> <xsl:value-of select="$iter" /> 

  <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="substring-after($csv,',')" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>    
 </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results in this output here:

```
Digraph G
{

  X -> D
  X -> B
  X -> C
  X -> A
  X -> E
  X -> C
}
```

---

I'm not going to lie: I found bits of XSL code, did some studying, and mangled something sort of effective into place. I at least have the terminal nodes working out okay; my problem now is getting the initial nodes.

My thinking is that I have to do a nested for-each loop somehow, passing in the  property as a parameter.

Pseudocode idea:

```
For each <node/name>
    Parameter n = <name>

    For-each <node/out> of n
        <name> -> <out>
```

I'm still trying to grasp the logic behind XSL, and as such, I'm trying to figure out how tokenize could be integrated into this problem. It's just not apparent to me yet. I've been constantly trying to arrive at a solution, but it's just not clicking with em yet.

Any help is extremely appreciated. Thank you for any time,
-Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="root/node/out">
 <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="." /> 
 </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="root/node/out">
 <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"> 
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="." /> 
   <xsl:with-param name="name" select="../name"/>
 </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
```

then make sure you declare that parameter in your named template and use it with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$name"/>` where you want it output and of course also make sure you pass it on in the recursive `call-template` with `<xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>`.

As a newbie to XSLT, I would suggest to look into the current version XSLT 3 or into the 11 years old XSLT 2 (where `tokenize` is available as an XPath function) instead of wrangling with the 20 years old XSLT 1 and recursive, callable templates.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!

I was trying something like that but I could get it to work for anything. Thanks again. :) I will look into newer functions and features. Since I'm new I have no idea about what's recent and what's deprecated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info has some info, and the respective versioned tags like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-3.0/info have more specific info.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a ton